# Appending reversed list in Scheme

Tags: list, functional-programming, append, scheme, reverse

I am learning Scheme and wanted to write a recursive program that reverses a given list.

In one test case however, I noticed that  `a (b c) e` -> `e (b c) a`.

What I'm trying to get is  `a (b c) e` -> `e (c b) a`.

This is what I have:

```
(define (deep-reverse lst)
(if (null? lst)
  '()
  (begin
    (display (car lst))
    (display "\n")
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        '()
        (append (deep-reverse (cdr lst)) (list (reverse (car lst))))
        ) //End of inner if
))) //End of begin, outer if, define
```

When I attempt to run the code with

> (deep-reverse '(1 (b c) (a b)))

I get:

```
1
(b c)
(a b)
mcdr: contract violation
expected: mpair?
given: 1
```

The issue is with `(list (reverse (car lst)))`, although in an isolated test case it works fine. Which leads me to believe that the issue may have to do with append.

Thank you in advance.

*Edit:* Going from `(list (reverse (car lst)))` to `(reverse (list(car lst)))` makes the code run without an error but doesn't reverse `(a b)` to `(b a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message explains, your problem is that you are trying to reverse a number. Firstly, let's remove some of the unnecessary conditions and debugging stuff in your program, arriving at this simpler program. Let's step through this program to see what's going on:

```
(define (deep-reverse lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (append (deep-reverse (cdr lst)) (list (reverse (car lst))))))
```

We start with

```
(deep-reverse '(1 (b c) (a b)))
```

Substituting the argument we get

```
(if (null? '(1 (b c) (a b)))
    '()
    (append (deep-reverse (cdr '(1 (b c) (a b))))
            (list (reverse (car '(1 (b c) (a b)))))))
```

Because the condition is `#f`, this simplifies to

```
(append (deep-reverse (cdr '(1 (b c) (a b))))
                (list (reverse (car '(1 (b c) (a b))))))
```

To evaluate the first argument, first find the `cdr`, and call `deep-reverse` on that. I will skip the steps here but you should easily be able to test that it works correctly.

```
(append '((b a) (c b)) (list (reverse (car '(1 (b c) (a b))))))
```

Next we evaluate the `car`:

```
(append '((b a) (c b)) (list (reverse 1)))
```

And here we see what the problem is: we can't reverse a single number!

The issue is that your `deep-reverse` should have two distinct behaviours recursively:

- on a number, or symbol, or other non-list entity, don't do anything, because it does not make sense to reverse a number
- on a list, deep reverse it

There are two reasons why your current program does not do this properly:

- it only does a shallow reverse on the elements of the list; that is, it won't deep reverse `'(((a b) (c d)) ((e f) (g h)))` correctly
- it fails if it ever encounters a number or other non-list, like a symbol

The easy fix is to add a condition to check if it's a `pair?` first before attempting to reverse it. If it's not `pair?`, then `lst` must either be `nil` (which we may leave as-is) or a non-list object (which we may also leave as-is)

```
(define (deep-reverse lst)
  (if (pair? lst)
      (append (deep-reverse (cdr lst)) (list (deep-reverse (car lst))))
      lst))
```

Finally, I should note that the pattern we are using here is really a `foldr` pattern. We can abstract away this pattern with `foldr`:

```
(define (deep-reverse xs)
  (cond ((pair? xs)
         (foldr (lambda (x y) (append y (list (deep-reverse x)))) '() xs))
        (else xs)))
```

But we note also that this is inefficient, because `append` is an expensive operation. Modifying the algorithm to a tail recursive one makes it clear that this is actually a `foldl`:

```
(define (deep-reverse xs)
  (cond ((pair? xs)
         (foldl (lambda (x y) (cons (deep-reverse x) y)) '() xs))
        (else xs)))
```

which is how such a function might be written in typical idiomatic Scheme, or as pointed out by Will Ness,

```
(define (deep-reverse xs)
  (cond ((pair? xs) (reverse (map deep-reverse xs)))
        (else xs)))
```

Comment: Did it on paper, what a neat method (all of them) of solving the problem. Thank you! If I may ask, what exactly does (if (null? list)) mean? Where does list come from, or does it take lst?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sorry, I did mean `lst`. I have corrected it, thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: If `lst` is `pair?` is is by deduction never `null?`

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, you're right. Silly mistake on my part! The extra condition is unnecessary since nil can be preserved.

Comment: Or it could be `((pair? xs) (reverse (map deep-reverse xs)))`.

Comment: @WillNess Nice! That's even simpler.